# Why doesnt this code display a basic wordpress settings page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress settings page but the code wont display the content. Im no techy so answers must be as plain as possible. I generated the code and it seems to want to find an options page but I input all the code into the plugin page. Any guidance apreciated thanks.

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Plugin Name
    Plugin URI: http://www.domain.com
    Description: Plugin description
    Author: S. Hawkins
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://www.domain.com
    */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'sppf_add_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sppf_settings_init' );


function sppf_add_admin_menu(  ) { 

    add_options_page( 'Power Funnels', 'Power Funnels', 'manage_options', 'power_funnels', 'power_funnels_options_page' );
}

function sppf_settings_init(  ) { 

    register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'sppf_settings' );

    add_settings_section(
        'sppf_pluginPage_section', 
        __( 'Your section description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_settings_section_callback', 
        'pluginPage'
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_radio_field_0', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_radio_field_0_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_checkbox_field_1', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_checkbox_field_1_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_checkbox_field_2', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_checkbox_field_2_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_select_field_3', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_select_field_3_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_text_field_4', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_text_field_4_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'sppf_textarea_field_5', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'sppf' ), 
        'sppf_textarea_field_5_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'sppf_pluginPage_section' 
    );


}

function sppf_radio_field_0_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='radio' name='sppf_settings[sppf_radio_field_0]' <?php checked( $options['sppf_radio_field_0'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
    <?php

}


function sppf_checkbox_field_1_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='sppf_settings[sppf_checkbox_field_1]' <?php checked( $options['sppf_checkbox_field_1'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
    <?php

}


function sppf_checkbox_field_2_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='sppf_settings[sppf_checkbox_field_2]' <?php checked( $options['sppf_checkbox_field_2'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
    <?php

}


function sppf_select_field_3_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <select name='sppf_settings[sppf_select_field_3]'>
        <option value='1' <?php selected( $options['sppf_select_field_3'], 1 ); ?>Option 1</option>
        <option value='2' <?php selected( $options['sppf_select_field_3'], 2 ); ?>Option 2</option>
    </select>

<?php

}


function sppf_text_field_4_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='sppf_settings[sppf_text_field_4]' value='<?php echo $options['sppf_text_field_4']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function sppf_textarea_field_5_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'sppf_settings' );
    ?>
    <textarea cols='40' rows='5' name='sppf_settings[sppf_textarea_field_5]'> 
        <?php echo $options['sppf_textarea_field_5']; ?>
    </textarea>
    <?php

}


function sppf_settings_section_callback(  ) { 

    echo __( 'This section description', 'sppf' );

}


function sppf_options_page(  ) { 

    ?>

<form action='options.php' method='post'>

        <h2>Power Funnels</h2>

        <?php
        settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
        do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
        submit_button();
        ?>

    </form>
    <?php

}   
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is actually calling these functions?

Comment: I was under the impression that a plugin only had that one page fpr settings. Well thats what all the tutorials tell me. The admin menu item appears but then everything is blank.

Comment: What is the plugin page named? I assume the options page it is trying to reference is named options.php.

Comment: I renamed the above page to options.php but that didnt alter things as it seems it would be calling itself. I think this is beyond me to be honest as it seems something is missing apart from this/above plugin page. I thought that page did produce the settings page. It was previously named powerfunnels.php At the moment its at that one plugin plage.

Comment: The reason it is looking for an options page is because your form has 'action="options.php"' Which is saying you are posting the contents of that form to options.php

Comment: Try leaving the form's action attribute blank.

Comment: From looking at several tutorials none mentioned creating a page. They just mentioned adding code to cretae the menu item then code for the settings (in that same plugin file) or so I presumed. I will most likely start looking for a programmer to be hionest although I like learning this is too complicated. its a completely new language but thought I could get through it one step at a time. OK

Comment: What happened when you left the action attribute blank on your form ?

Comment: Ok so that didnt work. But thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: By changing the end form code to this below the submit button and page header now show but with no output of the check options and text fields as in the above code.:                                                                                            <div class="wrap">
        <h2>My Plugin Options</h2>
        your form goes here

 <?php
 
  settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
  do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
  submit_button();
  ?>
 
 </div>